Recover nonce k from transaction details
Please I need the code to get the nonce k from r, s, message hash of a transaction and private or public of the the wallet

The nonce is a field in the transaction data.

@Ismael, I think by nonce k, he isn’t referring to the transaction nonce but rather to the ECDSA nonce.

The nonce k is supposed to be random but not too random. There's RFC 6979 that is used to generate a k from the message to be signed. So if the wallet follows RFC 6979 you should be able to obtain k from the transaction. It might not be possible to obtain k if wallet generates a random k. Perhaps a better place to ask that question is crypto.stackexchange.com.
